# Windows Phone 7 Styles on Desktop app

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, java-metro-framework

I' building an hobby project in WPF also decided to use Metro style theme to application. Is it possible to use `Windows phone 7` styles in desktop application instead of recreating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styles are in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Design folder by default.
These are regular Xaml files